# fasta: delete sequences after n length

Tags: perl, bash, fasta

I have multiple fasta files with 1000s of seqs in each file of varying length. I would like to  keep only the first 200 (n) bases from each sequence. How can I do this in Perl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to understand exactly what you mean without seeing an example but if you only need the first 200 characters per line just use `cut`:

```
cut -c1-200 file
```

Comment: Only prints the header lines for me.  I created a sample input file in http://pastebin.com/51nVG5nD

Comment: I couldn't run this script, instead i used the script below, which ran smoothly:  cut -c -200 file. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Ronn Are you saying my original answers `cut -c1-200` solved your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the sequence is printed on several physical lines, only print up through the 200th character.  A line starting with a wedge is a header line, which indicates the start of a new sequence.

```
awk '/^>/{ seqlen=0; print; next; }
    seqlen < 200 { if (seqlen + length($0) > 200)
            $0 = substr($0, 1, 200-seqlen);
        seqlen += length($0); print }' file.fasta >newfile.fasta
```

Oh, in Perl?

```
perl -nle 'if (/^>/) { $seqlen = 0; print; next }
    next if ($seqlen >= 200);
    $_ = substr($_, 0, 200-$seqlen) if ($seqlen + length($_) > 200);
    $seqlen += length($_);
    print;' file.fasta >newfile.fasta
```

Comment: Thanks Tripleee for your answer. I tried your perl script and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If the sequence is too long, keep only the interesting part:

```
$/ = '>';
<>;
while (my $seq = <>) {
    $seq =~ s/>$//;
    $seq =~ s/^(.*)//;
    my $id = $1;
    $seq =~ s/\n//g;
    $seq = substr $seq, 0, 200;
    print ">$id\n$seq\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 for the `$/` trick!  But this wrecks the newlines.  According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format the lines should be kept below 80 characters.

Comment: @triplee: It is just a recommendation :-) You can always add `$seq =~ s/(.{80})(?=.)/$1\n/g;` before the `print` line.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you consider using BioPerl for this sort of thing because it is very easy to accomplish these tasks and you don't have to worry about things like formatting. In the code below, the first argument to the script is your fasta and the second argument is a file to hold only the first 200 bases of each sequence.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::Seq;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $usage = "$0 infile outfile\n";
my $infile = shift or die $usage;
my $outfile = shift or die $usage;

my $seqin = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => $infile, -format => 'fasta');
my $seqout = Bio::SeqIO->new(-file => ">$outfile", -format => 'fasta');

while (my $seq = $seqin->next_seq) {
    my $first200 = $seq->subseq(1,200); # 1-based
    my $subseq = Bio::Seq->new(-seq => $first200, -id => $seq->id);
    $seqout->write_seq($subseq);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i solve it, if anyone interested in trying a another way to do it
i used a tool included in biolinux called *Fasta_formatter* to put the actual sequence in one line (-w 0), then trimming as @sudo_O said, and then finally back to the 80 letters width.

```
fasta_formatter -w 0 < FILE | cut -c1-LENGTH | fasta_formatter -w 80 > TRIMMED_FILE
```