# Select bases between 100 -200 and printing them along with header

Tags: perl, bash

I have a multi fasta file, from which I need to extract the bases ranging 100-200, including their corresponding headers. I know that 'cut -c 100-200' can do it without having their corresponding headers. Is there any way to do this in Perl or bash ??

Example file:

> 8YS68_00009_00025
>   GAGTTTGATCCTGGCTCAGAGCGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCTTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGGGCGTAGCAATACGTCAGCGGCAGACGGGTGAGTAACGCGTGGGAACATACCTTTTGGTTCGGAACAACACAGGGAAACTTGTGCTAATACCGGATAAGCTACGGGAAGATT
>   8YS68_00009_00027
>   GAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGAGCGAACGCTGGCGGCAGGCCTAACACATGCAAGTCGAGCGCCGTAGCAATACGGAGCGGCAGACGGGTGAGTAACGCGTGGGAACGTACCTTTCGGTTCGGAATAACTCAGGGAAACTTGAGCTAATACCGAATACGTCCGTAAGGAGAAAGATTTATCGCCGAAAGATCGGCCCGCGTAAGATTAGCTAGTTGGTGAGGTAAGGCTCACCAAGCGACGATCGTTAGCTTGTC
>   8YS68_00012_00035
>   GAGTTTGATCATGGCTCAGAACGAACGTTGGCGGCGTGGATTAGGCATGCAAGTCGAACGAATCCCATCTGGGTAACTGGGTGGGGGAAGTGGCGAAAGGGGCAGTAATGCGTGGGTAACCTACCTGGGGACCGGGATAGCCTCCTAACGGATGGGTAATACCGGATACGACCTTCGGAGGCATCTCCTGAAGG

Desired output:
seq id
------ATCGATCGATCG-----

seq id
------ATCGATCGATCG-----

seq id
------ATCGATCGATCG-----

Which means, I want to exactly extract the bases between 100-200 of each sequences, along with their headers. If a sequence is shorter than 100 bp, then ignore it.

Comment: Can you give a short input/desired output sample?

Comment: That is not [FASTA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format).  If your data is actually missing the ">" in front of the identifier then none of the approaches below will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the suggestions and working for sometime with this problem, I found a solution in Perl. Here is the important "loop" which does the job in Perl, which I wrote.

```
my $seq  = '';
my $head ;

while (my $seq = <IN>) {
if ($seq =~ m/^>/){
    $head = $seq;
    }
    else{
    my $dna .=$seq;
    my $subseq = substr ($seq, 100, 100);
    my $size = length($subseq);
    if ($size > 99){
        print OUT "$head";
        print OUT "$subseq";
        } 
  }
```

}

Thank you all for the help and support.

Answer (score 1):

Using **[Bio::SeqIO](http://search.cpan.org/~cjfields/BioPerl-1.6.901/Bio/SeqIO.pm)**, the following code will extract from 100 to 200 and print the headers.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict; 
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in_file = "fasta_dat.txt"; 

my $in = Bio::SeqIO->new (-file=> $in_file, -format=>'fasta');
my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file   => '>test.fasta',
                           -format => 'fasta');


while(my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {
    my $subseq = $seq->trunc(100, 200);
    $out->write_seq($subseq);
}
```

Update: or just adopt choroba's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335327/fasta-delete-sequences-after-n-length)

Answer (score 0):

If your desired output is another multi-fasta file, all you need is a little `awk`. Simply [substring](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) what you want.

```
awk '!/^>/ { print substr($0, 100, 100); next }1' file.fa
```

The `1` on the end returns true, enabling default printing of all lines in the file. The rest should be self explanatory. HTH.

---

A guess:

```
awk '/^>/ { h = $0; getline; print h RS substr($0, 100, 100) }' file.fa
```

or without `getline`:

```
awk '/^>/ { h = $0; next } h { print h RS substr($0, 100, 100); h = "" }' file.fa
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. Unfortunately, this gives the header of non-sequnces as well; the header is printed even if there are no corresponding sequences. How to tackle this ?

Comment: I thought you said you had a multi-fasta file? You will need to define non-sequence. As per the comments above, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16520781/edit) your question to include example data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can make use of the following python script :

```
    import sys,re
    i,list1 =0,[]
    for line in open(sys.argv[1]):
      if re.match(r'^[>|;]',line):  print line,
      else:
        for x in line:
          if x != "\n": i+=1
          if 100 < i < 200: list1.append(x)
    print "".join(list1)
```