# extracting fasta sequences based on position

Tags: perl, position, sequence, extract, fasta

I am a newbie to perl. Still learning.

I have a file in the fasta format. I would like to extract the sequences spanning a particular position. For example, from position 200 to 300

```
>Contig[0001]
TGCATCAAAAGCTGAAAATATGTAGTCGAGAAGTCATTTCGAGAAATTGACGTTTTAAGT
TTCGGTTTCCAAATTCAACCGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAATTGTCAGCAGTTAGAATTTC
TTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTTTTATATATTTTGATTCTGCATCAAAAGCTGAAAATATG
TAGTCTTGAAGTCATTTCGAGAAATCGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGG
ATGTATCTTCGCCAATAATTGTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTT
TTATATATTTTGATTCTGCATCAAAAGCTGAAAATGTGTAGTCTCGAAGTCATTTCGAGA
AATTGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAATTGT
CAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTTTTACATATTTTGACCCTGCATC
AAAAGCTGAAAATATGTAGTCTCGAAGTCATTTTGAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATT
ATGAAGCCCTTTTTATATATTTTGATTCTGCATCAAAAGCTGAAAATATGTAGTCTCGAA
GTCWTTTCRAGAAATTGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTC
GCCAATAATTGTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTTTTATATATTT
TGACTCTGCATCAAAAGCTGAAAATATGTAGTCTCGAAGTCATTTCGAGAAATTGACGTT
```

I would like to extract the sequences from position 200–300 from the sequence `Contig[0001]`. The output would be:

```
>Contig[0001]_200-300
AGAAATCGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAATT
GTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTT
```

I have almost 500 sequences in my fasta file and I have the required postions in a tab delimited file containing id start end.

It will be great if anyone could help me on this.

Thank you so much for all your help.I am not sure I can give the file containing the info regarding the positions.

newbie

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a question and answer site about programming. Please have a look at the [faq#howtoask]. You should always provide some code with your questions and show us what you have tried, or that you made an effort. I've answered this anyway because I found it interesting.

Comment: Also see similiar question **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520781/select-bases-between-100-200-and-printing-them-along-with-header)**

Answer (score 3):

One way. Content of `script.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my ($adn, $l, $header);

while ( <> ) { 
    chomp;

    ## First line is known, a header, so print it and process next one.
    if ( $. == 1 ) { 
        printf qq|%s_%s\n|, $_, q|200-300|;
        next;
    }   

    ## Concat adn while not found a header.
    if ( '>' ne substr $_, 0, 1 ) { 
        if ( ! $l ) { $l = length }
        $adn .= $_; 
        if ( ! eof ) { next }
    }   
    else {
        $header = sprintf qq|%s_%s\n|, $_, q|200-300|;
    }   

    ## Extract range 200-300 and insert newlines to set same length of 
    ## line than before.
    my $s = substr $adn, 199, 100;
    $s =~ s/(.{$l})/$1\n/g;
    printf qq|%s\n|, $s; 
    undef $adn;

    ## If not end of file, print the header of the following adn.
    if ( ! eof ) { print $header }
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl infile
```

That yields:

```
>Contig[0001]_200-300
AGAAATCGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAAT
TGTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTT
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you know how to get this into your program. Have a look at the [`substr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) function. It does what you want to do.

> ```
> substr EXPR,OFFSET,LENGTH
> ```

So basically what you need to do is:

```
my $snippet = substr($sequence, 200, 100);
```

---

On a second thought, have a look at CPAN: there's a module called [Bio::SeqReader::Fasta](https://metacpan.org/module/JAC/Bio-SeqReader-0.1.3/lib/Bio/SeqReader/Fasta.pm) that you can use to read the file and get the sequences. It's pretty well documented in my opinion and I'm intrigued by that. So here's a solution with it.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use Bio::SeqReader::Fasta;

# Put your positions here (start, end)
my @positions = (
  [ 200, 300 ], 
  [ 50, 180 ],
);

open my $fh, '<', '/path/to/file.fasta' or die $!;
my $in = new Bio::SeqReader::Fasta( fh => $fh ); # create the B::SR::F object

my $i = 0;
while ( my $so = $in->next() ) {
  # $so represents one dataset and is a Bio::SeqReader::FastaRecord

  say substr($so->seq(),               # we want a part of the sequence string
    $positions[$i]->[0],               # starting position
    $positions[$i]->[1] - $positions[$i]->[0]); # end - start --> length
}

close $fh;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using Perl and the Bio::SeqIO module. Run like:

```
./process_fasta.pl file.fa 200 300
```

Contents of `./process_fasta.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;
use Bio::SeqIO;

my $in_file = $ARGV[0];
my $start_pos = $ARGV[1];
my $end_pos = $ARGV[2];

my $in = Bio::SeqIO->new ( -file => $in_file, -format => 'fasta');
my $out = Bio::SeqIO->new( -file => ">$in_file.out", -format => 'fasta');


while (my $seq = $in->next_seq() ) {

    $seq->display_id( $seq->display_id() . "_$start_pos-$end_pos" );
    $out->write_seq( $seq->trunc($start_pos, $end_pos) );
}
```

Results:

```
>Contig[0001]_200-300
AGAAATCGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAAT
TGTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTTT
```

Answer (score 1):

I applaud those who used the `Bio::` modules, as I prefer them over writing something new.  Nevertheless, perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $end   = pop;
my $start = pop;
local $/ = '>';

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /(Contig.+)/;
    my ($header) = "$/$1_$start-$end\n";
    my $seq = ${^POSTMATCH};
    $seq =~ s/\s//g;
    print $header;
    print +( substr $seq, $start - 1, $end - $start ) . "\n";
}
```

Usage : `perl script.pl inFile start end [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Example: `perl script.pl data.fasta 200 300`

Output on your dataset:

```
>Contig[0001]_200-300
AGAAATCGACGTTTTAAGTTTCTGTTTCCAAATTCAAACGGATGTATCTTCGCCAATAATTGTCAGAAGTTAGAATTTCTTTCAACATTATGAAGCCCTT
```

The start and end parameters are `pop`ped off `@ARGV`, and then the record separator is set to ">".  As the file's read--a fasta record at a time--the header information is captured, leaving the sequence in `${^POSTMATCH}`.  All white space is removed from the sequence.  Finally, the reformatted header is `print`ed, as is the range of characters in the sequence.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Complete working flyweight script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $first=1;
if ( $ARGV[0] eq '-0' )
{
    shift @ARGV;
    $first=0;
}

die("Usage: cat <coords> | get_subseqs.pl (-0) <fasta files> > out; where coords is id, start, end. Use -0 if coords start with 0 instead of 1.\n") unless @ARGV;

# read coords
my %contigs = (); # id => [ start, end ]
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    my @row = split(/\t/);
    die("Require tab-delim: id, start, end\n") unless @row == 3;
    $contigs{$row[0]} = [ $row[1], $row[2] ];
}

# get subseqs
my ($id,$seq,$start,$end);
foreach my $infile (@ARGV) {
    open(IN, '<', $infile) or die($!);
    while (<IN>) {
        if (/>(\S+)/) {
            my $id2 = $1;
            print ">${id}_$start-$end\n", reformat(substr($seq, $start-$first, $end-$start+1)) if $id;
            if ( exists($contigs{$id2}) ) {
                ($id,$seq,$start,$end) = ($id2,'',@{$contigs{$id2}});
                delete($contigs{$id2});
            } else { $id=undef }
        } elsif($id) { $seq .= $_ }
    }
    close(IN);
    print ">${id}_$start-$end\n", reformat(substr($seq, $start-$first, $end-$start+1)) if $id;
    $id = undef;
}

sub reformat { # add newline every 60 bases
    my $seq = shift;
    my $seq2 = '';
    while ( length($seq) > 60 ) {
        $seq2 .= substr($seq,0,60)."\n";
        $seq = substr($seq,60);
    }
    $seq2 .= $seq."\n";
    return $seq2;
}
```